# Como enviar a senha já com o hash ao banco de dados

Tags: php, hash

Como poderia fazer para mandar uma senha com hash para meu banco de dados?

> Código

```
$PDO = db_connect();
$sql = "INSERT INTO users(nome, login, password, email,linkfb) VALUES(:name, :login, :senha, :email, :linkfb)";
$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':login', $login);
$stmt->bindParam(':senha', $senha);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindParam(':linkfb', $linkfb);
$senha = isset($_POST['senha']) ? $_POST['senha'] : null;
```

Comment: não entendi o motivo do downvote

Comment: não foi eu, alguém q me deu ...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer isto seria:

```
$senha = (isset($_POST['senha'])) ? password_hash($_POST['senha'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT) : null;

$stmt->bindParam(":senha", $senha);
```

Pode fazer estas transformações no método SET da sua classe que recebe os dados...
Espero que ajude...

Comment: SHA1 e MD5 não são hashs seguras e devem ser evitadas. SHA1 já pode ser quebrada e a string MD5 pode ter hashs conhecidas. Ele deve usar a função nativa do PHP para trabalhar com hash de senhas "password_hash": http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-hash.php

Comment: O MD5, SHA1, SHA2, SHA3... Todas essas são para propósitos gerais, não para senhas. Se você quer realmente usar, use o PBKDF2. Entretanto, existe alternativas melhores, como Bcrypt, Argon2 (...) que podem ser usadas com o password_hash, como indicado pelo Marcos.

Answer (score 0):

## hash

```
$PDO = db_connect();
$sql = "INSERT INTO users(nome, login, password, email,linkfb) VALUES(:name, :login, :senha, :email, :linkfb)";
$senha = hash('ripemd160', $senha);
$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':login', $login);
$stmt->bindParam(':senha', $senha);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindParam(':linkfb', $linkfb);
$stmt->execute();
```

ou

```
$senha = password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, 10);
```

## validação

```
$senha = isset($_POST['senha']) ? hash('ripemd160', $_POST['senha']) : hash('ripemd160', 'null');
```

caso use o `hash` a 'ripemd160' e o que você usara para validar o password novamente quando precisar dele

Comment: mas eu tou usando o hash man.

Comment: @Felipe pronto reajustado

Comment: eu não dei down vote não man.

Comment: @Felipe não irmão e pq vc ganhou um downvote sem motivo

Comment: ah simm, entendi man vlw, vc poderia me explicar oq significa esse "trava"?

Comment: cara vou mudar para o password_hash, essa trava e o que vc tera que usar para validar ela depois

Comment: e no caso como eu conseguiria testar se tem algo ex isso; $senha = isset($_POST['senha']) ? $_POST['senha'] : null; e já colocar o hash nela?

Comment: @william apareceu esse error aqui :

Comment: Warning: hash(): Unknown hashing algorithm: trava in C:\xampp\htdocs\skincs\add.php on line 8

Comment: @Felipe o 'ripemd160' e o algoritimo validador da senha... vc pode criar uma função para isso, mais nao e viavel pois o ´ripemd160´ e nativo

Comment: como eu poderia resolver vc pode me ajudar?

Comment: coloca 'ripemd160' no lugar de 'trava'